# Create week numbers using strftime (R)

Tags: r, calendar, time-series

I am adding a column with week numbers to a dataframe containing a calendar (list of days). Used `strftime` for that. It works but the week count starts at week 0. It should start at week 1, so I tried to add 1 to every element on the week number column. I get error message "Error in Calendar$WkNumber + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator". How could I eliminate that error? Thank you!

```
#Make daily time sequence with Time & DayWk columns 
Calendar <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2016/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/20"), "days"))
colnames(Calendar) <- "DateTime"
Calendar$WkNumber <- strftime(Calendar$DateTime,format="%W") 
Calendar$WkNumber <- Calendar$WkNumber + 1    #=> this line produces error

#Output for Calendar:
  DateTime      WkNumber
  1  2016-01-01       00
  2  2016-01-02       00
  3  2016-01-03       00
  4  2016-01-04       01
  5  2016-01-05       01
  6  2016-01-06       01
  7  2016-01-07       01
  8  2016-01-08       01
  9  2016-01-09       01
  10 2016-01-10       01
  11 2016-01-11       02
  12 2016-01-12       02
  13 2016-01-13       02
  14 2016-01-14       02
  15 2016-01-15       02
  16 2016-01-16       02
  17 2016-01-17       02
  18 2016-01-18       03
  19 2016-01-19       03
  20 2016-01-20       03
```

EDIT: PROBLEM IS 100% REPRODUCIBLE.

Comment: That line produce error because the "WkNumber" is `character` class. Convert to `numeric` and it should work.  i.e. `as.numeric(Calendar$WkNumber) + 1`

Comment: If you look at `str(Calendar)`, you can see that WkNumber is a character variable. --> You'll need to convert to numeric first.

Comment: Thanks very much. That explains. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to the comments:

```
Calendar$WkNumber <- as.numeric(strftime(Calendar$DateTime,format="%W"))+1
```